# Conversion error when converting datetime from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure. The date columns use `varchar` data type.

I want to be able to select data using the dates as the constraints.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStatusReport]
     @ShipFrom VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
     @ShipTo VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
AS
    SELECT 
        LOCATION, NEXT_DEPT,
        CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, REQ_DATE, 104) AS DATETIME) AS REQ_DATE,
        CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SCH, 104) AS DATETIME) AS SCH,
        Tool
    FROM 
        Status_Report 
    WHERE 
        (@ShipFrom IS NULL OR 
         CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SCH, 104) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ShipFrom, 104) AS DATETIME))
        AND (@ShipTo IS NULL OR 
             CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SCH, 104) AS DATETIME) <= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ShipTo, 104) AS DATETIME))
```

When I try to execute this stored procedure

```
exec spStatusReport '12/04/2018','NULL'
```

I want the user to be able to only pass one parameter either ShipFrom or ShipTO or even both but I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: you can set a default para like getdate() if SHIPTO param is null; and if SHIPFROM is null do like (getdate() - 1)

Comment: Your parameters are varchars instead of dates. This is making this a LOT more painful than it needs to be. Start with using the proper datatypes.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the `varchar` declaration. /facepalm

Comment: you can check the sample code below; to set default in case either or both params are NULL. You can check for this at start using IF statement. make sure to use BEGIN, END to encapsulate IF-statements.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the **literal string** `'NULL'` not the value `NULL`; they aren't the same. Also, you should use the ISO format for the date so it's not ambiguous. Try one of the following:

```
EXEC spStatusReport '20180412',NULL;

EXEC spStatusReport @ShipFrom = '20180412';
```

*Edit: Sean Lange is right in the comments as well. Your parameters should be a `date`, not a `varchar`. **Always** use datatypes appropriate for your data. `varchar` is far from a "one size fits all" datatype.*

Comment: I am actually executing this using a C# web application to the exec query passes like that by default

Comment: @Saahar No, C# doesn't. It definitely does not pass the literal string `'NULL'` for the value `NULL`. This sounds like the problem is therefore your C# code, not the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your where clause

```
declare @ShipFrom varchar(20) =NULL,
@ShipTo varchar(20)= NULL

--set @ShipFrom = getdate() - 1
--set @ShipTo = getdate()

select isnull(@ShipFrom,getdate() - 1) , isnull(@ShipTo,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you pass date/time values as `date`/`datetime` or a related data type.

Then, don't convert to strings to remove a time component.  SQL Server has better mechanisms.  And don't convert strings to strings; it just doesn't make sense.

You can also use `try_convert()` where appropriate:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStatusReport] (
     @ShipFrom VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
     @ShipTo VARCHAR(20) = NULL
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        LOCATION, NEXT_DEPT,
        CAST(CAST(REQ_DATE AS DATE) AS DATETIME)  AS REQ_DATE,
        CAST(CAST(SCH AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AS DATETIME) AS SCH,
        Tool
    FROM Status_Report 
    WHERE (@ShipFrom IS NULL OR 
           TRY_CONVERT(DATE, SCH, 104  >= TRY_CONVERT(DTAE, @ShipFrom, 104)
          ) AND
          (@ShipTo IS NULL OR 
           TRY_CONVERT(DATE, SCH, 104) <= TRY_CONVERT(DATE, @ShipTo, 104) 
         );
END;
```